# IOS- Universal Link with Firebase & bug with using location.href?

Tags: ios, firebase, ios-universal-links, firebase-dynamic-links, deeplink

I made a universal link and set them up both on Xcode and firebase dynamic link.

Seems like works really well with  tag in my own website.
ex)  link to myAPP

but when I try to use javascript such as  location.href = "universal_link"  .

That one does not works at all, and just leave me a message "the app is not installed, Go to appstore?"

Are there any issue using universal link with javascript?

If there is, how could I use javascript or any other ways in order to forward automatically to universal link when users accessing to my own website.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**You cannot use redirects this way with Universal Links — automatic forwarding (both Javascript and HTTP) is *not* possible in any form.**

Universal Links require some sort of explicit user interaction — a Javascript redirect does not qualify, unless it results directly from a user performing an action on a page object. Instead, you'll need to offer a static button or link the user can click.

Comment: You save my life. Thanks for helping.

Comment: Do you know any tricks that have the redirect things work well?

Comment: Unfortunately, no. At [Branch](https://branch.io) we deal with this all day every day, and there simply isn't a workaround at the moment. Believe me, we wish there was too!